# unable to read text file using spark and iPython

Tags: apache-spark, ipython

[image]

Hi I am just starting to learn spark and have configured my ipython to run spark but somehow I am not able to read textfiles, kindly suggest what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to access a file on your local system / master node, your path should start with `file:///users/...`. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Actually path provided without `file:///` tries to get file from HDFS and the file should reside in HDFS accordingly. In other hand if using a path on the local file system, the file must also be accessible at the same path on worker nodes. Either copy the file to all workers or use a network-mounted shared file system.